# Can't add nginx module - requires zlib

Tags: command-line, package-management, software-installation, nginx

I'm trying to add `nginx` **mp4** and **upload** module via

`./configure --add-module=/tmp/nginx-upload-module-2.2.0`

but it gives this(below) **error**. Whatever i tried, couldn't install the `zlib`. I need help..

```
./configure: error: the HTTP gzip module requires the zlib library.
You can either disable the module by using --without-http_gzip_module
option, or install the zlib library into the system, or build the zlib library
statically from the source with nginx by using --with-zlib=<path> option.
```

when i try to install `zlib` via

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` and this time it gives below **error**.

```
Package zlib1g-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

**Edit : Ubuntu version :**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: @dessert add this info to my question. it is 16.04.

Comment: On my 16.04 machine, `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev` simply installs this package, it should be [available in every supported version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/zlib1g-dev). I assume there's something else going on here…

Comment: what can be the reason. Is it possible to related with etc/apt/source/sources.list.d, if then what should i do ? i cant find the reason. i will lose my mind..

Answer (score 14):

A little late though. I guess you will need to install all the dependencies with the package. 
Try running:

```
apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: That would not solve the problem; if `zlib1g-dev` cannot be found, it will not suddenly appear after adding other packaes on the command line.

Comment: worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: No matter how hard I try, I always forget these! I've added to my newest docs (TLS, PCRE, and ZLIB support). Thanks for the reminder! Should be the accepted answer.